# What is "the everlasting covenant" of Isaiah 24:5?

Tags: isaiah

Isaiah 24:5-6 "...Changed the ordinance, Broken the everlasting covenant. Therefore the curse has devoured the earth..".  NKJV

Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges says with regard to "the everlasting covenant": "The expression is taken from Genesis 9:16 and refers to the covenant made after the flood with Noah".

But Benson commentary states it is , "The covenant made between God and Abraham".

Might "the everlasting covenant" refer to all or any of the Noah; Abrahamic; Israelite; Levitical; Davidic; or Christian Covenants?

Comment: There is also the mention of the _eternal covenant_. Hebrews 13:20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isaiah prophesied concerning the global destruction in the future in chapter 24:

> 1 See, the Lord **is going to** lay waste the **earth**
> and devastate it;
> he will ruin its face
> and scatter its inhabitants—

> 4The **earth** dries up and withers,
> the world languishes and withers,
> the **heavens** languish with the earth.

Even the heavens will be affected. The scope is rather universal.

> 5The earth is defiled by its people;
> they have disobeyed the laws,
> violated the statutes
> and broken the everlasting **covenant**.

Because of the universal nature of the destruction, I'd interpret this as the last covenant, i.e., the Christian covenant.

> 6 Therefore a curse consumes the earth;
> its people must bear their guilt.
> Therefore earth’s inhabitants are **burned** up,
> and very few are left.

> 19The earth is broken up,
> the earth is split asunder,
> the earth is violently shaken.

2 Peter 3:10 seems to echo these words of Isaiah:

> But the Day of the Lord will come like a thief. The heavens will disappear with a roar, the elements will be destroyed by **fire**, and the **earth** and its works will be laid bare.

Isaiah ended chapter 24 with these words:

> The **moon** will be dismayed, the **sun** ashamed; for the LORD Almighty will reign on Mount Zion and in Jerusalem, and before its elders—with great glory.

This is consistent with what Jesus said in Matthew 24:29

> Immediately after the tribulation of those days: 'The **sun** will be darkened, and the **moon** will not give its light; the stars will fall from the sky, and the powers of the heavens will be shaken.'

Might "the everlasting covenant" refer to all or any of the Noah; Abrahamic; Israelite; Levitical; Davidic; or Christian Covenants?

Because of the all-inclusive and universal nature of the destruction, I think it refers to the last covenant. Implicitly it incorporates all of the covenants before it.

Comment: When you say 'carries all of the covenants before it' do you mean it _incorporates_ all the other (supposedly separate and independent) covenants ? (In which case I agree.)

Comment: Thanks for the word choice. I agreed and modified :)

Comment: “The day of the Lord” seems to mean more than one thing. Besides being Saturday for Jews and Sunday for Christians, it can also mean 'the fateful day', and would then refer to a major upheaval of some sort. Whether it's a major personal upheaval, such as death, or a major societal upheaval, such as the end of the world as we know it, or the end of the earth.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that the OT covenants were all intended to be eternal:

- The Old Israelite Covenant is eternal (1 Chron 16:17, Jer 50:5, Ps 105:8)
- The Levitical Covenant is eternal (Lev 24:8, Num 25:10-13, Ps 106:30)
- The Davidic Covenant is eternal (2 Sam 23:5, 1 Kings 9:5, 2 Chron 13:5, Eze 37:25, 26)
- The Abrahamic Covenant is eternal  (Gen 17:9, 13, 19)
- The Noahide Covenant is eternal (Gen 9:16)

Let me deal with each of these to see which are still applicable, if any!

- Jesus is the fulfillment and continuation of the Abrahamic Covenant as per appendix 1
- Jesus is the fulfillment and continuation of the Levitical Covenant as per appendix 2
- Jesus is the fulfillment and continuation of the Davidic Covenant as per appendix 3

This leaves the Abrahamic covenant which is presumably still in force.

The Israelite covenant is continued in the Christian community.  According to Heb 8:7, 8, 9, the New Covenant was created, not because the Old was defective but because the people (literal Israelites) did not understand, rejected the old covenant and a New Covenant was made with new people, Christians, who accept the promises by faith.  Jesus made the same point in

- Matt 21:43, “Therefore I tell you that the kingdom of God will be taken away from you and given to a people who will produce its fruit.”  See also
- Gal 3:29, “If you belong to Christ, then you are Abraham's seed, and heirs according to the promise”.  Paul makes the same point in
- Rom 9:6-9, 11:11-22 where the old covenant was not revoked (it was immutable, Jer 31:35-37)

... but Christians, people of faith, were grafted into the original “olive tree”.  This is also confirmed by Eph 2:12 where Paul discusses Gentiles being absorbed into spiritual Israel becoming part of the ancient covenant promises, all by faith.

**Isaiah 24:5 - Which Covenant?**

In the OT, most (not all) references to a covenant are to the Israelite covenant as set out in Ex 19-23, parts of Leviticus and the book of Deuteronomy.  This covenant, among other things was a covenant of grace (see appendix 4), but it also contained the blessings and curses.

- The benefits/promises of the covenant are also clearly set out in Lev 26:1-13, Deut 28:1-14, blessings for obedience, and,
- Lev 26:14-39, Deut 28:15-68, curses for disobedience.

It is now simple to show that the discussion in Isa 24 is simply the repetition and fulfillment of the curses as listed above.  That is, when the people sinned by rejecting God, they removed themselves from the covenant protection and became subject to the vicissitudes of the real world as subjected themselves to the curses as listed above.

Thus, Isa 24 is a direct reference to the Israelite covenant.  That is, the Israelites would reap the results of their disobedience as clearly prophesied in the Covenant.  They did - they went into captivity, the land was cursed, etc, all because the people did not show the goodness and greatness of their loving God. They rejected God so God rejected them, Lev 26:44, Hos 9:17, 1 Sam 10:19, Ps 60:1, 78:59, etc.

**APPENDIX 1 - Abrahamic Covenant**

God intended, and twice stated, that the Abrahamic covenant was to have been eternal as recorded in Gen 17:9, 13, 17).  However, the literal descendants of Abraham ultimately rejected the covenant twice, which resulted in their dispossession – the first time at the hand of Nebuchadnezzar in the 6th century BC; and the second time in the first century AD when the Jews shouted, “we have no king but Caesar” (John 19:15, see also Hos 10:13.)  This is effectively confirmed at the first Jerusalem council where the primary symbol of the Abrahamic covenant, circumcision, was abandoned.  Despite this, Jews have always lived in and around Jerusalem from the time of Christ until the present day.

The sign of the Abrahamic covenant was circumcision (Gen 17:10, 11, 13) and involved the promise of the land.  If we assume that this covenant still applies, then it has indeed been proven to be eternal as Jews have always lived in Canaan.  For this who wish to become literal Jews, then they can go and live in Israel today and be circumcised.

Further, Jesus was the ultimate fulfilment of part of the Abrahamic covenant about Messiah as stated in Gal 3:16 - "*The promises were spoken to Abraham and to his seed. Scripture does not say “and to seeds,” meaning many people, but “and to your seed,” meaning one person, who is Christ.*"

**APPENDIX 2 - Levitical Covenant**

The purpose of the Levitical covenant was to teach and inculcate the plan of salvation (Deut 33:9, 10, Heb 9:8, 9, 11-14, 10:1-3, Col 2:16, 17).  That is, it symbolically taught about salvation by grace through the coming Messiah via His substitutionary death in the place of the sinner.  Thus, the sacrifices, Levites, priests and High Priest became a type of Jesus in various ways.

The token/sign (Heb: “oth”) of the Levitical covenant appears to have been the unleavened bread at the annual festival (Ex 13:6, 9, 16, Lev 24:8).

Thus Levitical covenant was fulfilled by Christ as our Great High Priest in the sanctuary in heaven (Heb 4:14-16, 5:10, 7:23-28, 8:1, 2, 9:1-28, 10:1-18.) - the earthly priesthood was destroyed and so was the earthly temple.

- Jesus was the fulfilment of what the sanctuary/temple typified, John 2:19-21, Heb 9:1-28, 10:1-18
- Jesus represented the foundation of the temple as well, 1 Peter 2:4-8 (Compare Isa 28:16, Ps 118:22)
- Jesus’ body was represented by the curtain in the temple, Heb 10:20.
- Jesus was the bread of life, John 6:35, 41, 48 (compare Ex 25:23-30, Lev 24:8).
- Jesus was the light of life, John 8:12, 9:5 (compare the lampstand Ex 25:31-39, Lev 24:3, 4, Isa 53:11, Ps 56:13, etc)
- Jesus provides the water of life, John 4:13, 14 (Compare the laver Ex 30:17-21.  See also 1 Cor 6:11)
- Jesus is the promised seed of the woman Gal 3:16 (compare Gen 3:15, and the Abrahamic Covenant)
- Jesus was the Passover Lamb and thus the promised Messiah, John 1:29, 1 Cor 5:7, 1 Peter 1:19 (compare Ex 12:1-14).
- Jesus is the High Priest of the New Covenant in fulfilment of the Levitical covenant, Heb 4:14-16, 5:10, 7:23-28, because He was “pure, blameless, set apart” exactly as the Levites were.  See also Heb 9:15, 12:24.
- Jesus provided the blood of the new covenant of which the communion ceremony was to be a memorial, Matt 26:28, Mark 14:24, Luke 22:20, 1 Cor 11:25, Heb 13:20, 1 Peter 1:19 (compare Ex 24:5, 8).

**APPENDIX 3 - Davidic Covenant**

The Davidic covenant was a type of the real king of the God's people called the kingdom of heaven in the NT.  Jesus is the promised King of the new Christian Community, ie, the Kingdom of Heaven, or, Kingdom of God, Luke 1:33, John 1:49, Acts 13:23, Rev 11:15.   Compare Jer 33:14-17, Eze 37:22.  Thus, Jesus inherits the Davidic Covenant.  He is also the “Son of David” (Matt 1:1-16) and “Son of God” as predicted in the Davidic Covenant (2 Sam 7); and His kingdom will never be defeated and is eternal, Luke 1:33, Heb 1:8, Rev 11:15, compare Ps 61:7, Isa 9:7, Ps 146:10.

Jesus is now seated on the eternal throne in heaven at the right hand of God, Matt 26:64, Mark 14:62, 16:19, Luke 22:69, Acts 2:33, 7:55-56 (standing), Rom 8:34, Eph 1:20, Col 3:1, Heb 1:3, 8:1, 10:12, 12:2, 1 Peter 3:22.  See also Ps 110:1, Matt 22:44, Mark 12:36, Acts 2:34, Heb 1:13, Rev 5.  Thus, Jesus fulfilled the Davidic covenant.

**APPENDIX 4 - Israelite Covenant of Grace**

That this Israelite Covenant was a covenant of transforming grace is confirmed by several ideas:

- The Israelite Covenant was a covenant initiated entirely by God alone, to save Israel.  God alone set out the requirements and blessings.  God makes it clear that they were selected as the chosen people, NOT because of any Israelite merit, but simply because God wanted to.  Deut 7:7, 9:5, 6, 10:15.
- The Israelite Covenant was a matter of the “heart” (Deut 6:5, 10:12, 16, 11:18, Ps 40:8, Jer 24:7, 31:33, 34, 32:38-40, Eze 11:19, 18:31, 36:26) and NOT mere regulations (1 Sam 15:22, Ps 40:6-8, 51:16, 17, Prov 15:8, 21:3, Isa 1:10-17, Jer 6:3-6, 20, Hos 6:6, Micah 6:6-8).  These references make it clear that the Old Covenant did not really include the animal sacrifices, and that they could not define nor atone for sin. (Heb 9:9, 10:4, Ps 51:16, 17, 1 Sam 15:22).  The animal sacrifices and the sanctuary ritual were part of the Levitical covenant which acted as teaching device that anticipated, and was a type of, the High Priestly ministry of Messiah.
- The Ark of the Covenant, containing the Covenant stone tablets of the 10 Commandments, was constructed in a highly symbolic way.  The 10 Commandments were inside the box and the “atonement cover” or “mercy seat” was placed above them.  Ex 25:17-22, 26:34, 30:6, 31:17, 37:9, 40:20, Lev 16:13; see also Heb 9:5.  This arrangement was placed in the Most Holy Place, in the sanctuary, and always remained at the center of God’s Covenant people.
- In Solomon’s prayer of dedication, he describes the (Israelite) Covenant as God showing “lovingkindness”, or, “steadfast love”, to people.  1 Kings 8:23, 2 Chron 6:14, See also Neh 1:5, 9:32, Ps 89:28, 33, 34, 103:17, 18, 111:4, 5, 9, Isa 54:10, 55:3.  This suggests that the Law of God, or the Moral Law, is an expression of God’s love and is just as eternal.

Comment: +1. It probably should be added that the last covenant to be broken is the world’s covenant with the Jerusalem dwelling priests, at the end of the millennium. To not yearly visit Jerusalem, during the feast of tabernacles, caused rain not to fall. While the worst offense thinkable caused fire to rain

Answer (score 1):

**ISAIAH 24:5** *The earth is defiled by its people; they have disobeyed the laws, violated the statutes, and broken the everlasting covenant.*

Context - and also just read the text. This passage is talking **all** the people of the **earth**. Not Israel, or *just* the Jews.

Covenant ‘bᵊrîṯ’ - can be translated ‘alliance’ - when God created Man (Adam), man was ‘in union’ (covenant) with God. Man needed God. Man was given dominion, but needed that alliance with his creator in order to ‘exercise’ that dominion. Adam could *not* have named the animals without this covenant. But ‘man’ broke this ‘tie’, took himself out from that covenant…. And Isaiah in this chapter spells out the consequences of this - clearly!

The everlasting covenant is that covenant under which man was created. The one that man left. The one that Jesus restored. Because it is everlasting.

The covenant God made after the flood was in effect of a promise *not* to destroy the earth via a flood. The Noahide Laws were in respect to (Gentiles) ‘righteous behaviour’, living ‘right’. The Abahamic covenant was specifically only for Gods nation. But, Isaiah here is talking about the (whole) earth, and (all) men.

Answer (score 1):

We must remember how highly idiomatic are the ancient languages. Just as the passage doesn't mean literal destruction of the whole earth, it only means a great part of the world facing drought and destruction, as with the ancient floods in the time of Noah, which were not literally global but global to various tribes who were annihilated. The word olam for eternal, everlasting doesn't have to be really eternal. The word of God is eternal, so his covenant is called eternal. The quality of the covenant from God's part can certainly be called eternal, so in this sense his covenants are eternal because God is eternal. To them the covenant was indeed eternal and forever so to speak. It means it was not a short period covenant.

Pharisee Paul says the Israelites cannot break the unconditional national covenant and promises (Rom 11:28-29) and they have broken the conditional covenant like before, and have become enemies of God. Despite breaking the salvation covenant, their national election remains in tact and the promise for restoration and special status remains. Only the Mosaic covenant of justification was conditional which has been broken by people with violation of the commands. Paul explains in details about the temporality of the Mosaic covenant, see Galatians 3 and 4, Romans 10 etc.

The Jews use the references of the covenant of Moses being eternal as evidence against the Messiah Yeshua and his new covenant, which serves as a stumbling block or veil of Moses on their eyes, just like the letters of Paul serves as stumbling block for the "Christians".

> Micah 4:5: “For all the peoples walk each in the name of its god, but we will walk in the name of the LORD our God forever and ever.”

See, BDB Hebrew Lexicon on עוֹלָם Olam H5769:

(1) of past time:
a. ancient time: ׳יְמֵי ע days of old Isa 63:9; Isa 63:11; Amos 9:11; Mic 5:1; Mic 7:14; ׳יְמוֺת ע Deut 32:7 ׳עַם ע Isa 44:7 ancient people; ׳גּוֺי מֵע Jer 5:15 ׳חָרְבוֺת ע old waste places Isa 58:12; Isa 61:4, compare Ezek 26:20 b; ׳פִּתְחֵי ע ancient gates Ps 24:7; Ps 24:9 ׳ארח ע Job 22:15 ׳נתבות ע Jer 6:16 ׳שְׁבִילֵי ע Jer 18:15 ׳גבול ע Prov 22:28; Prov 23:10 ׳במות ע Ezek 36:2 ׳מִן (מֵ)ע from of old Isa 64:3; Jer 2:20; Joel 2:2, of the fathers Josh 24:2, the prophets Jer 28:8, the ancient נפלים Gen 6:4 (Ezek 32:27 ᵐ5 Co for מערלים; but 1Sam 27:8 read מִטֵּלָם for מעולם We Dr HPS); ׳בהם ע long in them Isa 64:4 (text dubious)

(2) a. indefinite futurity, with preposition for ever, always (sometimes = during the lifetime); עֶבֶד עולם slave for ever Deut 15:17; 1Sam 27:12; Job 40:28 ׳עָבַד לע serve for ever Exod 21:6 (E), Lev 25:46 ׳עד ע 1Sam 1:22 ׳גְּאֻלַּת ע Lev 25:32 redemption at any time; ׳הֲרַת ע Jer 20:17 ever pregnant (womb); ׳כְּלִמַּת ע vJer 20:11 of persecutors of Jeremiah; ׳חרפת ע Jer 23:40 ׳שַׁלְוֵי ע Ps 73:12 alway at ease; ׳יְחִי לע (יחיה) may the king live alway 1Kgs 1:31; Neh 2:3 compare אֹרֶךְ יָמִים עולם ועד Ps 21:5 ישׁד עולם לפני אלהים Ps 61:8 so of the pious, לא ימוט ׳לע Ps 15:5 בל ימוט Prov 10:30, compare Ps 30:7 other phrase: Ps 37:27; Ps 37:28; Ps 41:13; Ps 55:23; Ps 61:8; Ps 73:26; Ps 121:8; Prov 10:25 אשׁירה ׳ע Ps 89:2 I will sing for ever (as long as I live), compare Ps 52:10; Ps 115:18; Ps 145:1; Ps 145:2 ׳הוֺדה ע Ps 30:13; Ps 44:9; Ps 52:11; Ps 79:13 other emotions and activities continuous through life Ps 5:12; Ps 31:2 = Ps 71:1; Ps 75:10; Ps 86:12; Ps 119:44; Ps 119:93; Ps 119:98; Ps 119:111; Ps 119:112; Mic 4:5, compare ׳לע Mic 2:9.

d. of God's covenant: ׳בְּרִית ע everlasting covenant Gen 9:16; Gen 17:7; Gen 17:13; Gen 17:19; Exod 31:16; Lev 24:8; Num 18:19 (all P), 2Sam 23:5; 1Chr 16:17 = Ps 105:10; Isa 24:5; Isa 55:3; Isa 61:8; Jer 32:40; Jer 50:5; Ezek 16:60; Ezek 37:26 covenant with Noah, ׳לְדֹרֹת ע Gen 9:12 (P); God remembers it 1Chr 16:15 = Ps 105:8; Ps 111:5 will not break it, ׳לע Judg 2:1 ׳אוֺת ע Exod 31:17 (P); ׳אוֺת עד ע Deut 28:46.
e. of God's laws: דבר(יםׅ Isa 59:21; Ps 119:89 משׁפט Ps 119:160 עדות vPs 119:144 vPs 119:152 ׳חק ע Exod 29:28; Exod 30:21 (E), Lev 6:11; Lev 6:15; Lev 7:34; Lev 10:15; Lev 24:9; (P), also Jer 5:22 (of bounds of sea); ׳חק עד ע Exod 12:24 (J), ׳חֻקַּת ע vExod 12:14 vExod 12:17; Exod 27:21; Exod 28:43; Exod 29:9; Lev 3:17; Lev 7:36; Lev 10:9; Lev 16:29; Lev 10:31; Lev 10:34; Lev 17:7; Lev 23:14; Lev 23:21; Lev 23:31; Lev 23:41; Lev 24:3; Lev 24:8; Num 10:8; Num 15:15; Num 18:23; Num 19:10; Num 19:21 (P) (most of these in fact specifically Jewish and temporary); temple to bear God's name, ׳עד ע 1Kgs 9:3 = 2Chr 7:16 ׳לע 2Kgs 21:7; 2Chr 33:4 consecrated ׳לע 2Chr 30:8 its ceremonies ׳לע 2Chr 2:3 Levitical priesthood, לשׁרתו ׳עד ע, 1Chr 15:2 Aaronic priesthood, ׳לברך בשׁמ ׳עד ע 1Chr 23:13 (twice in verse). feminine of God's promises: his word, ׳יקום לע Isa 40:8 promised dynasty of David, עד ׳(ה)ע 2Sam 7:13; 2Sam 7:16 (twice in verse); 2Sam 7:25 = 1Chr 17:12; 1Chr 17:14 (twice in verse); 1Chr 17:23, Ps 18:51 = 2Sam 22:51; 1Kgs 2:33; 1Kgs 2:45; 1Chr 22:10; Ps 89:5 ׳לע 1Kgs 9:5; 1Chr 28:4; 1Chr 28:7; 2Chr 13:5; Ps 89:29; Ps 89:37; 2Sam 7:29 (twice in verse) = 1Chr 17:27 (twice in verse); of holy land 1Chr 28:8, ׳אֲחֻזַּת ע Gen 17:8; Gen 48:4; Lev 25:34 (P); given ׳לע Exod 32:13 (J) 2Chr 20:7 ׳עד ע Gen 13:15, inherited ׳לע Isa 60:21; Ps 37:18 ׳עד ע Isa 34:17 dwelt in ׳עד ע Ezek 37:25 other blessings, ׳לע Deut 5:26; Hos 2:21 ׳עד ע Deut 12:28; 2Sam 7:24 = 1Chr 17:22; Ps 133:3 ׳שִׂמְחַת ע Isa 35:10; Isa 51:11; Isa 61:7 ׳דֶּרֶח ע Ps 139:24 ׳שׁם ע Isa 56:5; Isa 63:12 ׳אות ע Isa 55:13 ׳נאון ע Isa 60:15 Jerusalem to abide ׳לע Jer 17:25; Ps 125:1, compare Jer 31:40 ׳עד ע Ps 48:9.
g. of relations between God and his people, ׳לע 1Chr 29:18; Ps 45:18; Ps 85:6; Ps 103:9; Ps 145:21; Isa 57:16; Jer 3:5; Jer 3:12; Lam 3:31; Joel 2:26; Joel 2:27 ׳עד (ה)ע Ps 28:9; Mal 1:4.
h. of Messianic dynasty and king: ׳(ל)ע Ps 110:4 having divine throne Ps 45:7 name endures Ps 72:17 established Ps 89:38 God blesses him Ps 45:3 of his reign, ׳מעתה ועד ע Isa 9:6.
i. = indefinite, unending future: live ׳לע Gen 3:22 = Job 7:16 יִחְיוּ ׳הנביאים הלע Zech 1:5 the prophets, can they live for ever ? compare ׳חדל לע Ps 49:9 with negative never Ezra 9:12; Prov 27:24.

https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h5769/kjv/wlc/0-1/

Answer (score 1):

**What is “the everlasting covenant” of Isaiah 24:5?**

Isaiah 24:5-6 NASB  T**he word [Israelites] in bold added to the verse by me.**

> 5 The earth is also defiled [a]by its inhabitants, for they
> **[Israelites]**  violated laws, altered statutes, and broke the everlasting covenant. 6 Therefore, a curse devours the earth, and
> those who live on it suffer for their guilt. Therefore, the number of
> inhabitants of the earth decrease in number, and few people are left.

**"The everlasting covenant" refers to "Law Covenant" made between God and the nation of Israelites shortly after they left Egypt.** (Exodus 19:3-6) If the Israelites kept the covenant they would be people for their God, a kingdom of priest and a holy nation, and will have his blessings. (Deu. 28:1-14) If they violated the covenant they would be cursed (Deu .28 15-68)

**Blessings**

Exodus 19:3-6 NASB

> 3 And Moses went up to God, and the Lord called to him from the
> mountain, saying, “This is what you shall say to the house of Jacob
> and tell the sons of Israel: 4 ‘You yourselves have seen what I did to
> the Egyptians, and how I carried you on eagles’ wings, and brought you
> to Myself. 5 Now then, if you will indeed obey My voice and keep My
> covenant, then you shall be My [a]own possession among all the
> peoples, for all the earth is Mine; 6 and you shall be to Me a kingdom
> of priests and a holy nation.’ These are the words that you shall
> speak to the sons of Israel.”

**Curse.**

2 Kings 22:13 ASV

> 13 Go ye, inquire of Jehovah for me, and for the people, and for all
> Judah, concerning the words of this book that is found; for great is
> the wrath of Jehovah that is kindled against us, because our fathers
> have not hearkened unto the words of this book, to do according unto
> all that which is [a]written concerning us.

Daniel 9:5 NASB

> 5 we have sinned, we have done wrong, and [a]acted wickedly and
> rebelled, even turning aside from Your commandments and ordinances.

Answer (score 0):

Jeremiah 3:8 tells us that God divorced Israel. His covenant with her was not everlasting, although God's faithfulness would have been everlasting. His covenant with Israel was everlasting until Israel chose to leave God.

My interpretation is that His covenant ended because Israel was incapable of being faithful due to the sin nature that was ingested by Adam and Eve in the Garden of Eden.

The Covenant made by the blood of Jesus of Nazareth, the Son of God, will be everlasting. It's not that God's faithfulness has grown or become stronger. It's that in the New Covenant those that are in Christ are new creations (2 Corinthians 5:16-17). We are no longer controlled by the sin nature, not that we are automatically instantly sin free, but it is no longer a part of our nature. It's something we have, not something we are.

Because we are now free from sin, God's covenant with Israel (which all the nations are welcomed into by the blood of The Messaiah, Jesus of Nazareth) is now everlasting. God will not ever divorce us because we will no longer cheat on Him as Israel did in the Old Covenant. We will not continue living in sin. We will stop sinning eventually and we will live in freedom and glory on the New Earth forever. It will be everlasting.

God's original Covenant with Israel was also a covenant of grace. But it's simply a principal of scripture that adultery constitutes the end of a covenant. It's not that that person failed from a performance standpoint. It's that through their sexual unfaithfulness they demonstrated they didn't want to be in the covenant of grace. They of course have the choice to leave.

In order for the covenant to be everlasting, adultery must and will be avoided at some point. It's not that God is looking to punish every act of adultery, because we know He isn't. That's why Jesus died.

It's that in the Old Testament, due to Israel's sin nature that came down from Adam and Eve, it was impossible for them to stay faithful forever. Eventually they would go back to their sin nature. For those in Christ we are no longer slaves to sin. We've been set free by the blood of The Christ. So even if we cheat on God, He knows we will stop eventually. He's committed to that future with us and that future is no longer impossible. Rather, it is now a guarantee.

If you are defining the Old Covenant according to the potential it had due to God's faithfulness it could be defined as 'everlasting'. I don't see that as a logical stretch.

Comment: Hi Swarbrick, welcome to BH-Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [code of conduct](https://www.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/conduct). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since Isaiah 24 seems to address all of mankind, not just the Israelites, I believe we need to look at the time God referred to the everlasting covenant He made with all of humanity. We need to look to Genesis 9 when He refers to that covenant very clearly. Yes, His side of the covenant is the rainbow: not to ever again destroy the entire world with flood waters. But what is our side of the covenant?

Clearly, He repeats it at least two times in Genesis 9: mankind's role is to "be fruitful and multiply and fill the earth" with people made in the image of God. The reason most folks don't see this is their assumption that the earth is already full of people. Not true! You could take every man, woman and child in the entire world today and give them each 1000 square feet to live on, and they would ALL fit in the State of Texas! Furthermore, because so few babies are being born today to replace those dying or soon to die, demographers project the entire world population beginning to decline in about 30 years, with no way to reverse this decline. Japan already is seeing deaths far outweigh births. It takes 2.1 babies per female to just break even. America has been below this value since 1975.

Bottom line, we are not doing our part of the everlasting covenant. As a result, "Therefore earth’s inhabitants are burned up,
and very few are left." Isaiah 24:6.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).